# Silverlight : Modify Canvas.Zindex of button on mouseover / focused state from style

Tags: silverlight

I want to modify the ZIndex of a button on mouseover / focused state from the style and not from codebehind.

Comment: It works. http://stackoverflow.com/a/3609642/1292399

Comment: I dont think it works for Silverlight..I need it for Silverlight as well.. ( modified the title..actually I need this for Silverlight)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant really do this with a style.

The best you can hope for in that regard is to create a Behavior that will change the ZIndex property. But then you have got to create an [Attached Property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11056466/how-to-put-behavior-in-style-for-textbox-in-silverlight) for the Behavior so you can set it in a Style. It will work, but you should consider another approach.

You can define a Visual State in your Page/View. Then using [Interaction Triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900353/wpf-silverlight-states-activate-from-xaml), you can trigger that Visual State with a GoToState Action on MouseOver and GotFocus.

---

**Edit:** If it is re-usability you seek, derive a type from Button and use your type instead. You can then define any behavior that comes to mind from code in your Button.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Problem is I need to have common style for button because this style needs to be reused in multiple pages/views for many buttons across the application.